# Capitalize the first letter in each string in a list

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a list containing several strings. I want to capitalize the first letter of each string in the list. How can I do it using list methods?
Or I have to use regex here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `capitalize` on each string. Note that it lowercases the rest of the letters

```
l = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'list']
print [x.capitalize() for x in l]
['This', 'Is', 'A', 'List']
```

If you need to preserve case on the other letters, do this instead

```
l = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'BOMBAST']
print [x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in l]
['This', 'Is', 'A', 'List', 'BOMBAST']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=['a', 'test','string']

print [a.title() for a in x]
```

`['A', 'Test', 'String']`

Since `regex` is tagged too, you can use something like following

```
>>> import re
>>> x=['a', 'test','string']
>>> def repl_func(m):
       return m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper()


>>> [re.sub("(^|\s)(\S)", repl_func, a) for a in x]
['A', 'Test', 'String']
```